# Find index of iterator in STL container - need template function

Tags: c++, list, templates, stl, find

I want to have a function with interface like this:

```
template<typename T, typename R> int find_index (const T& list, const R& value);
```

As I know, there is `find()` in STL that returns iterator. I need to return index of iterator (even for non-indexed containers such as `std::list`). I tried this code:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
int find_index (const T& list, const R& value)
{
    int index = 0;
    for (T::const_iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++, index++)
        if ((*it) == value)
            return index;
    return -1;
}
```

But compiler shows error on `it` - seems like it is not allowed to get `const_iterator` from templated typename. Can I go around it?

At the worst case I can pass begin and end iterators to find_index arguments, but it looks not so fine. Would be thankful for elegant solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for (typename T::const_iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it, ++index)
```

should solve your problem.

When using dependent types (types depending on template parameters), the compiler does not know that `const_iterator` is a type until it instantiates the template with a concrete type, it could also just be a static variable or whatever. Using the `typename` keyword, you tell him that `const_iterator` is really a type.

In C++11 you can also circumvent the whole `typename` issue using the `auto` keyword:

```
for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it, ++index)
```

---

If you already have the iterator (maybe from some other operation), you can also just compute the distance from the list's begin to this iterator:

```
#include <iterator>

int index = std::distance(list.begin(), it);
```

But since this has linear complexity for a `std::list`, using your self-made `find_index` function is a better idea than `std::find` followed by `std::distance`, at least performance-wise.