# How to find future RoadIDs for a car in Veins?

Tags: omnet++

In a scenario I am simulating in Veins, I need to determine for a `car` node it's next `RoadID` value. Since this information is stored in the `.route` file of the simulation, I think it can be extracted.

The current `RoadID` value can be returned by the `traci->getRoadID()` function. I explored how it extracts this ID and could go to that point where new modules are added by the `addModule()` function but I am unable to understand how it extracts this information.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, as @user4786271 noted, this is currently not implemented in Veins 4 alpha 2, nor in SUMO 0.22.

The feature [was added](http://sumo.dlr.de/trac.wsgi/changeset/18494) in [ticket #1823](http://sumo.dlr.de/trac.wsgi/ticket/1823) and is scheduled for addition in SUMO 0.24. The corresponding code to add support to Veins 4 will be:

```
int32_t TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::getRouteIndex() {
    return traci->genericGetInt(CMD_GET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE, nodeId, VAR_ROUTE_INDEX, RESPONSE_GET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know currently Veins does not have such a built-in feature. You can do something like `getRouteId()` for a certain vehicle. That will return you the route.

Next, within your application (`.cc` file) you can read the `<example_name>.rou.xml` of your current example which probably contains something like:

```
<route id="4" edges="0/1to1/1 1/1to2/1"/>
```

and from there you could infer the roadID, which in fact is the the name of the edge.

I know still the result would not be optimal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well yes, the result as such will not be optimal. In fact, in the module `TraCICommandInterface`, there's a function `getRouteEdgeIDs()` which takes the `routeID` and returns a list of the edges on the route, so it makes a file lookup unnecessary. 
But, the main problem is that if a route has recurring edges, how do I determine which is the next edge that my car is going to take of these recurrences?

Comment: don't know if you have tried how  `getRouteEdgeIDs()` works. Maybe it returns a list or IDs ordered as they appear in the route, also allowing duplicates. If that doesn't work, you can switch to thinking about *what if a route has recurring edges, while `getRouteEdgeIDs()` does not return duplicates...*

Comment: I have tried the function. It returns a list of edges in the routes with recurrence included. And if it doesn't return recurrences, then, well, the route information will be of no use then because I only have the knowledge of the current edge. Even if I store the knowledge of the previous routes taken, for long route programs, edge matching and finding will be inefficient.
The problem can be solved if, in some way, I am able to find the _index_ of the current edgeId.

Comment: by index you mean its position of a edge in the list that was returned by `getRouteEdgeIDs()`?

Comment: Exactly. If I can get this index, I can simply say that the edge on the next index is the required edge. But unfortunately, the `connection.query()` for TraCI socket allows only certain legal queries such as the retrieval of this edge list on a route. I tried to experiment with some other queries to see if I can get his index but couldn't run them. You have any other ideas about it?

Comment: given that I have not misunderstood you: if you know the name of the edge you are looking for you can use `find` method of the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930887/find-index-of-iterator-in-stl-container-need-template-function

Comment: Well actually you misunderstood it. I know how to find the index of an element in a `std::list`. What I am saying is what if there are two entries with the same edge name (that is, the route contains a looping path)? Then which index should be used.
Anyway, the feature is not present. I got a ticket opened for the development.